# Stop EACCES errors with npm/node on Ubuntu?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, sudo, node-modules

#### Setup the system environment

```
$ lsb_release -a 2> /dev/null | grep Desc
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS

$ sudo apt-get install build-essential
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js && sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install nodejs && sudo npm update -g npm
$ sudo npm install -g yo generator-angular && cd /tmp && mkdir b && cd $_
```

#### Generate (yeoman)

```
/tmp/b $ yo angular
[?] Would you like to use Sass (with Compass)? No
[?] Would you like to include Bootstrap? No
[?] Which modules would you like to include? 
 ⬢ angular-animate.js
 ⬢ angular-cookies.js
 ⬡ angular-resource.js
 ⬡ angular-route.js
 ⬢ angular-sanitize.js
 ⬢ angular-touch.js
```

#### Errors

[npm-debug.log](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/aa5b26d14f029423dd3a)

---

Is there some trick—short of `chown`ing `/usr/lib/node_modules`—that will stop these errors from occuring?

Comment: A quick shot, though not the optimal way: manually, as root, remove `/home/username/.npm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

*(feel free to use a path other than `$HOME/npm`)*

1. Remove everything but `npm` from global `node_modules` folder (`/usr/lib/node_modules`)
2. `$ mkdir "$HOME/npm"`
3. `$ npm config set prefix "$HOME/npm"`
4. `$ printf "NODE_PATH=$NODE_PATH:$HOME/npm/lib/node_modules\nPATH=$PATH:$HOME/npm:$HOME/npm/bin\n" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`